# Inquiry on Performance Differences in Pipeline Image Processing with GeoServer on AWS

Tags: geoserver

currently utilizing GeoServer on AWS for pipeline image processing tasks. I have encountered significant differences in processing speed and quality between two GeoServer instances, despite them operating in the same AWS environment. Both systems are utilizing identical storage configurations, with matching database capacities, indexing, and RDS specifications.

After reviewing various settings to identify the cause of these performance discrepancies, I have yet to determine a clear reason. I am reaching out with a few questions in hopes of resolving this issue:

Are there any other factors within the AWS environment that could potentially affect GeoServer's performance?
Could there be any GeoServer internal settings that might cause performance variations, even with identical specs and configurations?
Are there additional aspects I should examine to optimize performance?
I seek your advice and assistance in minimizing these performance differences and achieving an optimized setup. I appreciate your prompt response and am willing to provide any further information required